# If $A$ is closed then $B$ must be open in $\Bbb R^2$ .

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $A$ and $B$ be two disjoint non empty subsets of $\Bbb R^2$ such that $A \cup B$ is open in $\Bbb R^2$. Then

1. If $A$ is open and $A \cup B$ is connected then $B$ must be closed in $\Bbb R^2$
2. If $A$ is closed then $B$ must be open in $\Bbb R^2$ .
3. If both $A$ and $B$ are connected then $A \cup B$ must be disconnected.
4. If $A \cup B$ is disconnected then both $A$ and $B$ are open.

Consider  $A=\{(x, y): x^2+y^2<1\}$, and .$B=\{(x, y): 1\le x^2+y^2<2\}$. be two disjoint non empty subsets of $\Bbb R^2$ such that $A \cup B $ is open in $\Bbb R^2$. Here $A$ is open and $A \cup B$ is connected but $B$ is not closed. So option $1$ is not true. Also we see that $A$  and $B$ both are connected with $A \cup B $ is connected. So option $3$ is also not true.

Also I have know the result $A \cup B$ is disconnected if two set $A$ and $B$ such that $A \neq \phi$, $B \neq \phi$ with $\overline A \cap B = \phi$ , $ A \cap  \overline B = \phi$ . Please provide me a counter example for option $4$. And how to prove $2nd$ in general. Thanks

Comment: $(0,1)×(0,1) \neq \{(x, y): x^2+y^2<1\}$.

Comment: You ask for a counterexample for item 4.  What is your basis for rejecting the truth of item 4?

Answer (score 1):

For 1)  and 3) you have the right examples except for your mis-understanding of the product of intervals

2. $B=(A\cup B)\cap A^{c}$ which is the intersection of the open sets $A\cup B$ and $A^{c}$.

For 4) take $A=\mathbb Q \setminus \{0\}$ and $B=\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$

Comment: Your explanation for option 2 is very nice. But I could not understand counter for 4.

Comment: @Merabhai $A\cup B=(-\infty,0) \cup (0,\infty)$ so $A \cup B$ is disconnected. Neither $A$ not $B$ is open.